# Include two label in Barcode using BarcodeLib in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode, barcode-printing

I have developed an application that encodes string into barcode.
For this I used BarcodeLib. I can include a Label into Barcode.

My question is How to include two labels in barcode?

I am using vs2010, c#, winforms and BarcodeLib library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a library online to generate barcode with two labels. Sprire.Barcode is the library provided.